# How can I save an item to a hotkey?

Tags: factorio

I remember seeing this in one of the tips you get when you start a game, but I can't find it again.

You're supposed to be able to "save" an item to a hotkey, so that no other items get placed there, and items of that type will get put there automatically. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set a filter to quickbar slot by middle-mouse button (clear by control middle mouse button). It can be changed in the options.

The same technique can be used to reserve some of the slots in cargo wagon for some specific items.

Comment: What is this on OSX?

Comment: The hotkey is CMD+RMB on OSX